# How to upload images from local storage into cloudinary?

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

In laravel 8 app I need to upload images from local storage into cloudinary ( with cloudinary-laravel 1.0)

and looking at description :

```
// Store the uploaded file in the "lambogini" directory on Cloudinary with the filename "prosper"
$result = $request->file->storeOnCloudinaryAs('lambogini', 'prosper');
```

How can I convert my storage path into uploaded request( $request->file ) ?
uploaded request seems the obly oject which can work with methods of this library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file in your storage already you can upload with the following instead:

```js
$uploadedFileUrl = Cloudinary::upload('path/to/your/image.jpg')->getSecurePath();
```